# How do I get the timezone of an SQL server?

Tags: sql-server, timezone

How can I query the current timezone setting for an SQL server with respect to some offset like UTC?

Comment: You can use `DATETIMEOFFSET` [but it is not DTS aware](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3173/handle-conversion-between-time-zones-in-sql-server--part-1/) or the new sql server 2016 [AT TIME ZONE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt612795.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: I think this question is asking how to get not the time zone but the current server’s zone offset. You can easily get this with `DATEPART(TZOffset, SYSDATETIMEOFFSET())`

Answer (score 12):

```
DECLARE @TimeZone VARCHAR(50)
EXEC MASTER.dbo.xp_regread 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE','SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\TimeZoneInformation','TimeZoneKeyName',@TimeZone OUT
SELECT @TimeZone
```

Comment: The main purpose is to record the time stamp, so i am looking if any such thing would be available in the settings or so..and i hope getutcdate() gets the current UTC time..need to get the date timestamp with reference to UTC..can i get that?

Comment: @pavanmanideep It sounds like you’re actually interested in [`SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/sysdatetimeoffset-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)…? But your question didn’t lend itself to someone answering with that.